# Trouble calling method from another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

object1.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface object1 : NSObject

+ (id) randomObject;

@end
```

object1.m

```
#import "object1.h"
@implementation object1

+ (id) randomObject{
    ...
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "object1.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
...
-(IBAction)randButton:(id)sender{
    object1 *ro1=[[object1 alloc]init];
    [ro1 randomObject]; //issue is here
}

@end
```

I am getting the issue "No visible @interface for 'object1' declares the selector 'randomObject'" and I'm not entirely sure I'm supposed to make it visible as it's already in the imported object1.h file.

How do I get this to work?

[Edit: missed a line]

Comment: you have declared a class method and trying to call it on an instance. the way you call class methods are like this 

[ClassName classMethod]; 

in your case it would be just [object randomObject]; (you don tneed to make instance )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use + you create class method and to access class method you don't create object, you call:

```
 //[CLASS_NAME method_name];
[object1 randomObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interface and implementation change the + to a -.

A + indicates a `Class` method. Something like...

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:];
```

What you need in an `instance` method something like...

```
[myString length];
```

Also, I think there are issues in what you're trying to do.

What are you trying to do?